# Http get call returns too many results. ::JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http, asynchronous

I have a function:

```
private getValues() {
  this._values = [];
  this._watchlistElements.map(v =>
    this.http.get('http://localhost/getValue/' + v.xid)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this._values.push(res.json());
       console.log(this._values.length);
  }))
};
```

After calling that function, Im getting a result which looks like:

[image]

**My question is** how to check the actual length of the `_values` variable? This solution works but as you can see it returns a result with every iteration, like in a loop. How to make it to return just one, final result? In this case `-->` the length should be just **7**.

Comment: just put after map function

Comment: @Mahi But then the function returns 0, as the length of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. Just used observables from rxjs.

First of all import the observables into your component:

`import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';`

Then, the fixed function:

```
private getValues() {
  this._values = [];
  Observable.forkJoin(
    this._watchlistElements.map(v => {                                                          
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/getValue/' + v.xid)
      .map(res => res.json());
  })
  ).subscribe(v => {
    this._values = v;
    console.log(this._values.length);
  });
};
```

The result => **`7`**.

Answer (score 1):

Capturing each call in a Promise, then waiting for all is a good approach:

```
Promise.all(this._watchlistElements
  .map(v => new Promise(resolve => this.http.get(...).subscribe(res => resolve(res.json())))))
    .then(arrayWithResultFromEachCall => console.log(arrayWithResultFromEachCall.length))
```